# NestJS: constructor injection with abstract class

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, abstract-class

I am developing NestJS project with typescript.

I have an abstract class:

```
export abstract class JobExecutor {

  private readonly name: string;

  constructor(
    // I injected the JobConfig instance in constructor
    protected readonly config: JobConfig,
  ) {
    this.name = this.getName();
  }
  
  abstract getName(): string;

  // non-abstract method also needs to access `config`
  doJob = async ()=> {
    const configMetaData = this.config.metadata;
  }

}
```

Then, my concrete class which extends the above abstract class, itself is injected to another caller but that is not a problem so I don't show that here:

```
@Injectable()
export class HeavyJobExecutor extends JobExecutor {
   //implement the abstract method
   getName(): string {
       // it accesses the injected `config` from the abstract class,
       // BUT at runtime, this.config is null, why?
       return this.config.heavyjob.name;
   }
}
```

When run the code, I get error that the `this.config` is null in `HeavyJobExecutor`. Why is that?

Since both abstract class & concrete class need to access that `config` instance, I prefer to inject it in abstract class' constructor. But how can I access the `config` in the concrete class?

Comment: What happens if you decorate the abstract class with `@Injectable()` as well?

Answer (score 9):

You can use custom [providers](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers#class-providers-useclass)

Where you define the provider `HeavyJobExecutor`

```
@Module({
  providers: [HeavyJobExecutor],
})
export class SomeExecutorModule {}
```

replace with

```
@Module({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: JobExecutor,
      useClass: HeavyJobExecutor,
    },
  ],
})
export class SomeExecutorModule {}
```

And where you inject this provider, specify the type of the abstract class

```
constructor(
   private readonly heavyJobExecutor: JobExecutor
) {}
```

Also you need to add the `Injectable` decorator to abstract class

```
@Injectable()
export abstract class JobExecutor
```

Comment: Adding the `@Injectable()` annotation to the abstract class is what I was missing in my app. Very easy to overlook. Seeing your answer reminded me to check 

Comment: very good. thanks for helping

Comment: What if there is another provider that also extends `JobExecutor` - let's say `lightJobExecutor` - and is injected alongside `heavyJobExecutor`?
How should the `@Module` be in this case? And how the injection should be done?